# Как вывести PopupMenu при нажатии кнопки в ToolBar?

Tags: android, popupmenu

Есть метод обработки нажатия пункта меню в `ToolBar`:

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.selection_list_goto: 
//          Отсюда хочу вывести Popup menu строкой
//      PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(Contex, View);
                    break;
```

но не понимаю что задать в качестве `View`, а что в качестве `Contex` или как вывести `PopupMenu` при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: Вам где его надо оборажать? В центре экрана или внизу? Или справа наверху?

Comment: В центре вверху

Comment: Второй параметр означает "У какой вьюшки расположить меню".  Сюда вам надо передать объект, к которому она привяжется

Comment: как получить вьюшку ToolBar?

Comment: Что нужно указать, чтобы окно отобразилось над ToolBar?

Comment: Мм, думается в разметку toolbar по центру положить обычный view, указать ему id, в активити достать его и уже передавать в popupMenu

Comment: Cказать насколько это верно не могу, но так должно по идее отцентровать и прижать к верху ваше меню

Comment: mToolbar.getRootView() подойдет для получения View ToolBar?

Comment: Незнаю, проверьте

Comment: Вы хотите нажимать на сам тулбар (а не какой-то виджет на нем), чтобы появлялось PopupMenu ? Не думаю, что пользователь оценит такой изыск

Answer (score 1):

В докуметнации достаточно доступно, подробно и даже на русском языке [описано создание айтема меню](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#PopupMenu) с выпадающим списком - в общем то достаточно повесить слушатель на нужный `View`:

Создаем элемент в `OptionsMenu`, для которого при клике нужно отображать `PopupMenu` (отличие в том, что вешаем слушатель на клик атрибутом `android:onClick`):

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/ic_selection_list_goto"
    android:onClick="showPopup" />
```

Создаем метод, обрабатывающий клик элемента, помещенного в `OptionsMenu`:

```
public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
       popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
       popup.inflate(R.menu.popupMenu);
       popup.show();
}

// действие при кликах в созданном PopupMenu

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.archive:
            archive(item);
            return true;
        case R.id.delete:
            delete(item);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

где *R.menu.popupMenu* - ресурс для `PopupMenu`.
*R.id.archive*, *R.id.delete* - Айдишники пунктов в самом ресурсе `PopupMenu`

PS: если `this` по каким то причинам недоступен, для получения контекста в данном случае можно использовать контекст самого `View` получив его методом `getContext()`. Например:

```
 PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(v.getContext(), v);
```

Так же можно зайти с другой стороны - не создавать отдельный метод для обработки клика (хотя это и проще), а получить `View` из колбэка `OnOptionsItemSelected`:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.selection_list_goto: 
                View v = item.getActionView();
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(v.getContex(), v);
                popup.inflate(R.menu.popupMenu);
                popup.show();
                break;
```

но этот способ я не проверял.